# Grabbing the key, closest to a value of an array

Tags: php, arrays

This post may or may not make sense, but I will try to explain it to the bestest of my abilities.

So, let's say we have an EXP value of `30` for a user.

```
$level = array(
    '1' => '0', '2' => '6', '3' => '13', '4' => '21', '5' => '29', '6' => '37', '7' => '46', '8' => '56', '9' => '66', '10' => '76', '11' => '87', '12' => '99', '13' => '111', '14' => '124', '15' => '138', '16' => '153', '17' => '168', '18' => '184', '19' => '201', '20' => '219', '21' => '238', '22' => '258', '23' => '279', '24' => '301', '25' => '325', '26' => '349', '27' => '376', '28' => '403', '29' => '432', '30' => '463', '31' => '495', '32' => '529', '33' => '565', '34' => '602', '35' => '642', '36' => '684', '37' => '729', '38' => '775', '39' => '824', '40' => '876', '41' => '931', '42' => '989', '43' => '1049', '44' => '1114', '45' => '1181', '46' => '1252', '47' => '1328', '48' => '1407', '49' => '1490', '50' => '1578', '51' => '1671', '52' => '1769', '53' => '1872', '54' => '1981', '55' => '2096', '56' => '2217', '57' => '2345', '58' => '2479', '59' => '2621', '60' => '2771', '61' => '2928', '62' => '3095', '63' => '3270', '64' => '3455', '65' => '3650', '66' => '3855', '67' => '4072', '68' => '4301', '69' => '4542', '70' => '4796', '71' => '5064', '72' => '5347', '73' => '5645', '74' => '5960', '75' => '6292', '76' => '6641', '77' => '7010', '78' => '7399', '79' => '7809', '80' => '8242', '81' => '8698', '82' => '9179', '83' => '9686', '84' => '10221', '85' => '10786', '86' => '11381', '87' => '12008', '88' => '12670', '89' => '13368', '90' => '14105', '91' => '14881', '92' => '15700', '93' => '16564', '94' => '17475', '95' => '18436', '96' => '19449', '97' => '20517', '98' => '21645', '99' => '22833'
);
```

Now, if you match 30 in this array. This means that the users level would be Level 5 because 29 is closet to Level 5, and Level 6 will require 37 EXP.

Now, my question is. How would I make a function that can return the value Level 5. It would kind of be one of the `closest` functions I've seen on here, but it would have to return the `key` of the array as that's where the level is.

I don't really know where to start with this, I don't know how this is possible. I imagine with a for statement, but I have no clue where I'd even start.

Again, hope I explained this well enough.. It's hard to explain!

Comment: Is your array always sorted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This simple approach will fit your needs:

```
function get_level($exp)
{
   $levels = array(
    '1' => '0', '2' => '6', '3' => '13', '4' => '21', '5' => '29', '6' => '37');  // and so on

   asort($levels);  // sort array if necessary

   $last_key=0;

   foreach ($levels as $key => $level) {
        if ($exp < $level) {
           return $last_key;
        }
        $last_key = $key;
   }

   // if number is bigger than biggest level values:
   return "Too big!";  // ...or whatever is good 4 you
}
```

Test it [here](http://phpio.net/s/1mpn).

Comment: This was exactly what I needed, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

```
function getClosest($search, $arr)
{
    $closest = null;
    $level = null;
    foreach ($arr as $key => $item) {
        if ($closest === null || abs($search - $closest) > abs($item - $search)) {
            $closest = $item;
            $level = $key;
        }
    }
    return $level;
}

$level = array(
    '1' => '0', '2' => '6', '3' => '13', '4' => '21', '5' => '29', '6' => '37', '7' => '46', '8' => '56', '9' => '66', '10' => '76', '11' => '87', '12' => '99', '13' => '111', '14' => '124', '15' => '138', '16' => '153', '17' => '168', '18' => '184', '19' => '201', '20' => '219', '21' => '238', '22' => '258', '23' => '279', '24' => '301', '25' => '325', '26' => '349', '27' => '376', '28' => '403', '29' => '432', '30' => '463', '31' => '495', '32' => '529', '33' => '565', '34' => '602', '35' => '642', '36' => '684', '37' => '729', '38' => '775', '39' => '824', '40' => '876', '41' => '931', '42' => '989', '43' => '1049', '44' => '1114', '45' => '1181', '46' => '1252', '47' => '1328', '48' => '1407', '49' => '1490', '50' => '1578', '51' => '1671', '52' => '1769', '53' => '1872', '54' => '1981', '55' => '2096', '56' => '2217', '57' => '2345', '58' => '2479', '59' => '2621', '60' => '2771', '61' => '2928', '62' => '3095', '63' => '3270', '64' => '3455', '65' => '3650', '66' => '3855', '67' => '4072', '68' => '4301', '69' => '4542', '70' => '4796', '71' => '5064', '72' => '5347', '73' => '5645', '74' => '5960', '75' => '6292', '76' => '6641', '77' => '7010', '78' => '7399', '79' => '7809', '80' => '8242', '81' => '8698', '82' => '9179', '83' => '9686', '84' => '10221', '85' => '10786', '86' => '11381', '87' => '12008', '88' => '12670', '89' => '13368', '90' => '14105', '91' => '14881', '92' => '15700', '93' => '16564', '94' => '17475', '95' => '18436', '96' => '19449', '97' => '20517', '98' => '21645', '99' => '22833',
);

echo getClosest(30, $level);
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://phpio.net/s/1mo3)**

Answer (score 0):

This should work (in function form, where `$exp` is the EXP value and `$array` the array with levels):

```
function closest($exp, $array) {
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        $difference[abs($value - $exp)] = $key; // calculate the difference for each key
    }

    ksort($difference, SORT_NUMERIC); // sort array by key
    $closest_key = current($difference); // get the first (= closest) key by value
    return $closest_key;
}

echo closest(30, $level);
```

Which results in:

```
5
```

If the `$level` array stays the same you could embed it in the function like this:

```
function closest($exp) {
    $level = array(
        '1' => '0', '2' => '6', '3' => '13', '4' => '21', '5' => '29', '6' => '37', '7' => '46', '8' => '56', '9' => '66', '10' => '76', '11' => '87', '12' => '99', '13' => '111', '14' => '124', '15' => '138', '16' => '153', '17' => '168', '18' => '184', '19' => '201', '20' => '219', '21' => '238', '22' => '258', '23' => '279', '24' => '301', '25' => '325', '26' => '349', '27' => '376', '28' => '403', '29' => '432', '30' => '463', '31' => '495', '32' => '529', '33' => '565', '34' => '602', '35' => '642', '36' => '684', '37' => '729', '38' => '775', '39' => '824', '40' => '876', '41' => '931', '42' => '989', '43' => '1049', '44' => '1114', '45' => '1181', '46' => '1252', '47' => '1328', '48' => '1407', '49' => '1490', '50' => '1578', '51' => '1671', '52' => '1769', '53' => '1872', '54' => '1981', '55' => '2096', '56' => '2217', '57' => '2345', '58' => '2479', '59' => '2621', '60' => '2771', '61' => '2928', '62' => '3095', '63' => '3270', '64' => '3455', '65' => '3650', '66' => '3855', '67' => '4072', '68' => '4301', '69' => '4542', '70' => '4796', '71' => '5064', '72' => '5347', '73' => '5645', '74' => '5960', '75' => '6292', '76' => '6641', '77' => '7010', '78' => '7399', '79' => '7809', '80' => '8242', '81' => '8698', '82' => '9179', '83' => '9686', '84' => '10221', '85' => '10786', '86' => '11381', '87' => '12008', '88' => '12670', '89' => '13368', '90' => '14105', '91' => '14881', '92' => '15700', '93' => '16564', '94' => '17475', '95' => '18436', '96' => '19449', '97' => '20517', '98' => '21645', '99' => '22833'
    );

    foreach($level as $key => $value) {
        $difference[abs($value - $exp)] = $key; // calculate the difference for each key
    }

    ksort($difference, SORT_NUMERIC); // sort array by key
    $closest_key = current($difference); // get the first (= closest) key by value
    return $closest_key;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correct, you can try the following (in c language):
(suppose that you are matching 30)

```
int your_exp = 30;
int i, array_length = 6;
int EXP[] = {0, 6, 13, 21, 29, 37};
for(i=0; i<=array_length - 1; i++)
{
   if(EXP[i] >= your_exp)
      printf("Your level is: %d", i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it recursively like so:

```
function getClosest($level, $input, $index)
{
    $index++;
    if($index == count($level))
        return $index;
    if($input < $level[$index+1] && $input >= $level[$index])
        return $index;
    return getClosest($level, $input, $index);
}
```

Which you'd call this way:

```
echo getClosest($level, 13554, 0); //prints 89
```